# James-Stein regularizing covariance like a mean

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

In James-Stein's estimator we have a $p$-dimensional random vector $X\sim N_{p}(\mu ,I)$ where $\mu \neq 0$ and the goal is to estimate the mean vector using the single ($n=1$) data vector $X$. The squared loss of any estimator $\hat{\mu}$ is measured:
\begin{equation*}
L(\hat{\mu},\mu)=\sum_{i=1}^{p}(\mu_{i} - \hat{\mu}_{i})^{2}=\| \mu-\hat{\mu} \|_{2}^{2}
\end{equation*}
This leads to risk:
\begin{equation*}
R(\hat{\mu})=\mathop{\mathbb{E}} \| \hat{\mu}-\mu \| ^{2}
\end{equation*}
The risk of the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) $\hat{\mu}_{MLE}=X$:
\begin{equation*}
R(\hat{\mu}_{MLE})=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X_{i}-\mu_{i})^{2}=p\cdot var(X_{1})=p
\end{equation*}
I read this book: [High‐Dimensional Covariance Estimation](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118573617). In page 30 of this book, example 7, the author shrinks the MLE toward the zero. For doing this, the author finds $\beta_{0}$ the minimizer of $R(\mu_{\beta})$ where $\mu_{\beta}=\beta X$ :
\begin{equation}
\beta_{0}=(1+p/\| \mu \|^{2})^{-1}
\end{equation}
**I do not understand the calculations done to get the $\beta_{0}$**. Can someone explain how to find $\beta_{0}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk of $\mu_\beta$ is 
\begin{align}
R(\mu_\beta) &= \sum_{i=1}^{p}\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\beta X_{i} - \mu_{i})^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{p} \mathop{\mathbb{E}}( \beta^2 X_{i}^2 - 2\beta X_i \mu_i + \mu_{i}^2) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta^2 (1 + \mu_i^2) - 2\beta \mu_i^2 + \mu_{i}^2 \\
&= a\beta^2 + b\beta + c,
\end{align}
where $a = \sum_{i=1}^{p} (1 + \mu_i^2) > 0$, $b = - 2\sum_{i=1}^{p} \mu_i^2$, and $c = \sum_{i=1}^{p} \mu_i^2$.  The risk is minimized when $\frac{d}{d\beta} R(\mu_\beta) = 2a\beta + b = 0$, i.e. for
\begin{align}
\beta_0 &= \frac{-b}{2a} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p} \mu_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{p} (1 + \mu_i^2)} \\
&= \frac{\| \mu \|^2}{p + \| \mu \|^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{p + \| \mu \|^2}{\| \mu \|^2}\right)^{-1} \\
&= \left(1 + \frac{p }{\| \mu \|^2}\right)^{-1}. \\
\end{align}